# How to use $_GET?

Tags: php, session, get, fetch

I have the following login script, where i do use sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    header("Location: start.php?id=$id");
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $x1 = $_POST['x1'];
    $x2 = $_POST['x2'];
...
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE x1='".$x1."' AND x2='".$x2."'");
        if($query->num_rows === 1){

            $row = $query->fetch_object();
            $id = $row->id;

                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header("Location: start.php?id=$id");

                        3more queries
                        exit();
```

start.php will be just:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

I thought $_GET['id'] would be stored on the server so that $_GET should be displayed. The fetch_object is working. I know that, because it will be displayed the right way at "id=$id" at the browser. So would someone be that friendly and could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: what you get on start.php? empty, null, 0, what

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. right, there won't be displayed anything. it is just a empty page. ok, i guess that $_GET just will be submitted over the URL. when "id" will be stored into the URL then it should be displayed i think or am i wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just manually going to start.php?id=1 to see what happens? If it displays '1', then the problem is not in start.php. I also notice that it seems like you are doing more processing (3more queries) *after* you call Header('Location:...'). That is not really a good idea. The only thing you should do after sending a redirect location is a die/exit.

Comment: even if i try manually, there wont be diplayed anything. i changed the queries to another place but that wont solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any URL rewriting going on, such as through .htaccess? That can trim off the query string unless you specify the [QSA] flag.

Comment: when i will display hidden files, i can't find any .htaccess with rewrite rules

Comment: the problem was that mod_rewrite was enabled on the server! thanks.

Comment: You probably want to leave mod_rewrite enabled. All in all, it does way more good than bad. Instead, just try to find the actual rule that is being triggered by this request and add the [QSA] flag to the end of it, which is the Query String Append command to keep get variables intact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $_GET superglobal is defined as part of the URL string:

```
http://example.org/index.php?foo=bar&baz=1
```

In index.php:

```
echo $_GET['foo']; // bar
echo $_GET['baz']; // 1
```

So $_GET is not stored on the server, but is passed with each HTTP request, as is $_POST, but that is passed in the HTTP headers rather than simply appened to the end of the URL.

Comment: Even $_POST isn't stored. Very ambiguous quote.

Comment: Did you just look through my recent stuff to find something to (incorrectly) criticize because I pointed out how retarded your 4 deep nested ifs was? I never said POST is stored. In fact, I explicitly said POST is sent in the same way as GET, with each HTTP request.

Comment: Hmm? I just found the answer to be vague. Please correct it, whoever you are.

Comment: Since my original reply was deleted, I'll repost it more nicely - it's not vague. It's very clear. And you shouldn't go hunt for 3 month old posts to criticize when someone disagrees with your answer as being inefficient and bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` variables are those passed via the URL, i.e. `index.php?foo=bar&baz=qux` (`foo` equals `bar`, `baz` equals `qux`).

These variables are not stored on the server as a part of the session, but rather only exist with that request. If you want to store information on the server as a part of the session, you should use `$_SESSION` instead, which will exist within the current session, regardless of the request.

Comment: hello and thanks for answering, that i do understand. when the $_GET will be passed over the url, start.php should be able to read it out or not? why does the echo phrase wont display the id, when it is stored in the url?

Comment: If you pass it through the URL to `start.php` in your redirect (as it looks like you are trying to do), then yes it will be readable, otherwise not. I think it does not really help to pass the session ID through a `$_GET` variable though seeing as you have already saved it into `$_SESSION`.