# PHP CMS Trouble

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am in the middle of creating a CMS in PHP & MySQL for the company I work for and have hit a bump in the road.

So I have a table that fetches and lists everything from a table, then next to each record is an edit button.

This button has the following code:

```
<?php 
    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="editRecord.php?id='.$id.'">
    <input type="submit" name="Edit"></form></td>'; 
?>
```

Which then obviously goes to that page, however on the next page i have the following code and it's not running anything.

I don't understand why it's not fetching the information from the database if I have given it the ID...

```
include 'login/connection.php'; 
$id = $row['id']; 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM vehicleOrderForm WHERE id = ' $id ' "); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

That code is at the start and then further down is this;

```
<?php
    echo $row["id"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $make =  $row["make"];
    $varient = $row["varient"];
    $stockno = $row["stockno"];
    $transmission = $row["transmission"];
    $cc = $row["cc"];
    $colour = $row["colour"];
    $delivery = $row["delivery"];
    $stock = $row["stock"];
    $sold = $row["sold"];
    $customer = $row["customer"];
    $tax = $row["tax"];
    $comments = $row["comments"];
?>
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $id; ?></h1>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <p>Make:</p>
    <?php echo '<input type="text" name="make" value="'.$make.'" />;' ?>
    <p>Varient:</p>
    <input type="text" name="varient" value=" <?php echo $varient; ?>" /> <br />
    <p>Stock Number:</p>
    <input type="email" name="stockno" value="<?php echo $stockno; ?>" /> <br />
    <p>Transmission:</p>
    <input type="number" name="transmission" value="<?php echo $transmission; ?>" /> <br />';
    <p>CC:</p>
    <input type="username" name="cc" value="<?php echo $cc; ?>" /> <br />';
    <p>Colour:</p>
    <input type="text" name="colour" value="<?php echo $colour; ?>" /> <br />';
    <p>Expected Delivery:</p>
    <input type="text" name="delivery" value="<?php echo $delivery; ?>"/> <br />';
    <p>In Stock:</p>
    <input type="text" name="stock" value="<?php echo $stock; ?>"/> <br />';
    <p>Status:</p>
    <input type="text" name="sold" value="<?php echo $sold; ?>"/> <br />';
    <p>Customer:</p>
    <input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $customer; ?>"/> <br />';
    <p>Tax:</p>
    <input type="text" name="tax" value="<?php echo $tax; ?>"/> <br />';
    <p>Comments:</p>
    <input type="text" name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>"/> <br />';
    <input type="Submit" name="Edit" value="Edit">'; 
</form>
```

If anyone can understand it, that would be great.

Comment: You're using `POST` but also sending the `$id` via query string? That's strange. Anyways, the first thing you need to verify is if you're getting value of `$id` on `editRecord.php` page.

Comment: `WHERE id = ' $id '` - my naive guess would be that you probably don’t _have_ any records with an actual id value like `SPACE CHARACTER somenumber SPACE CHARACTER` in your database …

Comment: `$id = $row['id'];` - where do you expect any `$row` variable to come from here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use $\_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725323/how-to-use-get)

Comment: To make your query secure (assuming `id` is an integer) without using a prepared statement, cast `$id` as an integer before feeding it to your query.

Answer (score 0):

That form around the `Edit` button looks like it's totally useless.. You can't sent the form with POST method, and attach an id to the action url: that param won't be sent.

**Solution 1**: If you can, I would suggest you to switch to `GET` param and use an anchor. Like this:

```
<?php echo '<td><a href="editRecord.php?id='.$id.'">Edit</a></td>'; ?>
```

And edit your code on page `editRecord.php` as follows:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // you need to receive the param from the url
```

**Solution 2**: If you want to keep the `<form>`, you should write the following code:

```
<?php 
    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="editRecord.php"> '.
        '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />'.
        '<input type="submit" name="Edit"></form></td>'; 
?>
```

And on page `editRecord.php`:

```
$id = $_POST['id']; // you need to receive the param from the url
```

Comment: Yes, but the `$id` is attached to the action url, thus it's a `GET` param. The OP is not about the possible security issues..

Comment: The content on this page WON'T be seen by people looking for sql injections issues.. Anyway, I removed the misleading code

Comment: Just to be clear you must assume that a future researcher will be educated by your post and assume it is okay to copy-paste any portion of it.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, looks like i was having a stupid 5 minutes. Thanks for your help.