# How can I convert named PHP $_GET parameters to a numerically indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a website URL like the following:

> www.localhost.com/page?x=1&y=2

Now I want to get all the GET parameters in an array like below:

```
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725323/how-to-use-get

Comment: take a look at : http://www.shodor.org/~kevink/phpTutorial/nileshc_getreqpost.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $_GET global variable in PHP itself.

```
$array = [];

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {

array_push($array, $value);
}
```

You can use PHP `array_values()` if you want to get all the values of that array without considering the keys:

```
$array = array_values($_GET);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read from global $_GET directly and create array with keys:

```
$array = [
 'y' => $_GET['y'],
 'x' => $_GET['x'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the newer syntax:

```
$array = [];
foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
{
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Why should one do that and not directly use `$_GET`?

Comment: This makes just a copy of the references in `$_GET` in `$array` with the same indices.

Comment: Is there a difference between the above and `$array = $_GET` ?  This array is also not numerically indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP's built-in [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to accomplish the same thing. Per the documentation:

> Returns an indexed array of values.

This will maintain the order of values as they originally were in the `$_GET` array. For example:

```
/**
 * With $_GET input array of:
 *
 * ['a' => 'apple', 'c' => 'cantaloupe', 'b' => 'banana']
 */

$indexed = array_values($_GET);

/**
 * Will output an indexed array of:
 *
 * [0 => 'apple', 1 => 'cantaloupe', 2 => 'banana']
 */
```

Note that this maintains the original sort order and will not reindex the output array (even if your associative array keys are numeric).

Comment: This was my first thought.  But I'd have thought order likely important here.  Parameters could be re-ordered leading to different results. `?x=2&y=3`.

Comment: No, the `array_values` function operates very similarly to a foreach loop and does not modify the order. There does exist a possibility of inconsistent ordering due to browsers, javascript frameworks, and even caching layers like CloudFlare. For that reason, you should really consider a less brittle solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.  I'd go with `$array = [$_GET['x'], $_GET['y']]` if you know which parameters will be passed.  Perhaps though order isn't important here.