# how to grab part of query string in url with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: php, url, query-string

I have a couple of url strings like below:

```
admin.php?filter_status=New
```

```
admin.php?filter_status=New&currentpage=2
```

and

```
admin.php?entry_search=Ready
```

```
admin.php?entry_search=Ready&currentpage=3
```

How can i grab always the value between `?` and `&` ?

So: `entry_search=Ready` or `filter_status=New`

In case the url is" `admin.php?entry_search=Ready&currentpage=3`;

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` gives me `entry_search=Ready&currentpage=3` and it should always give me only `entry_search=Ready`

Comment: You might want to look up $_GET

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use $\_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725323/how-to-use-get)

Comment: @waterloomatt No, because i have a lot of different query strings and i want to catch them all in 1 variable. So i need a way to catch, whatever it is, everything inbetween `?` and `&`

Comment: @john can you give some more detail on what the reason is you want to capture that part of the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the first in the `$_GET` superglobal, so:

```
$val = reset($_GET);
$key = key($_GET);
```

To use the query string:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $array);
$val = reset($array);
$key = key($array);
```

If you really need a string then:

```
$result = "$key=$val";
```

Comment: This is exact what i needed! thnx