# Using GET to correlate with switch statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a switch statement to execute a section of code to run a query to generate an html list. I would like use the get value from the URL to correlate with the switch statement IE list.php?=types would run the query and script to generate the html table for types. But I can't quite figure out how it make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

**list.php**

```
<?php 

include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
__GET = $list
switch ($list) {
    case 'roads':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM roads";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    //$stmt->bind_param("i", $roadID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>Option</td>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['roadName']."&nbsp;(". $row['reportingMark']. ")</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    break;
    case 'types':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM types";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    //$stmt->bind_param("i", $roadID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>Option</td>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['typeName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    break;
    case 'packs':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM packs";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    //$stmt->bind_param("i", $roadID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>Option</td>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['packName']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    break;
    case 'origin':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM origins";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    //$stmt->bind_param("i", $roadID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>Option</td>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['origin']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    break;
    default:
    echo 'Not found';
    break

}
```

Comment: `$list = $_GET['nameOfUrlParamter'];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use $\_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725323/how-to-use-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the $_GET superglobal.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

?type=roads

```php
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    switch($_GET['type']) {
        //etc
    }
}
```