# How to insert input value into array data php?

Tags: javascript, php

I created a form like this, How should I do so that the value of the form field is entered into the php data array?

Expected that the value of the submitted data is entered into this line:

```
$customer_details = array(
  'first_name'    => "value input first_name",
  'email'         => "value input email",
  'phone'         => "value input phone"
);
```

form input:

```
<form>
  <label>Name:</label>      
  <input name="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50"><br>
  <label>Phone:</label> 
  <input name="phone" type="text" maxlength="100"><br>
  <label>Email:</label> 
  <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="100"><br><br>
  <button id="pay-button">Pay!</button>
</form>
```

The php code and html form are in 1 file.

Comment: Look at the `$_GET` array, all that data is already in that ARRAY, so you dont need another

Comment: `snap.pay('<?=$snapToken?>');` What is this?

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, it's a function in javascript when pressing the "pay!" button, I shouldn't have written it so as not to confuse

Comment: `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use $\_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725323/how-to-use-get)

Comment: Hi Kmoser, Sorry that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs 2 attributes (action, method) and your button needs 1 (type) :

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
  <label>Name:</label>      
  <input name="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50"><br>
  <label>Phone:</label> 
  <input name="phone" type="text" maxlength="100"><br>
  <label>Email:</label> 
  <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="100"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="pay-button">Pay!</button>
</form>
```

So the submit button will handle the form using the same page.

You can check if the form is handled using this :

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
    //use your form
}
```

Then you have an existing array *$_GET*. You can access your datas using the name of your input (ex : *$_GET['first_name']*).

If you want to use your *$customer_array*, then :

```
$customer_details = array(
  'first_name'    => $_GET['first_name'],
  'email'         => $_GET['email'],
  'phone'         => $_GET['phone']
);
```

UPDATED

The final result should be :

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
    
    $customer_details = array(
      'first_name'    => $_GET['first_name'],
      'email'         => $_GET['email'],
      'phone'         => $_GET['phone']
    );

    //Any other treatment...

} else {

  <form action="#" method="GET">
    <label>Name:</label>      
    <input name="first_name" type="text" maxlength="50"><br>
    <label>Phone:</label> 
    <input name="phone" type="text" maxlength="100"><br>
    <label>Email:</label> 
    <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="100"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="pay-button">Pay!</button>
  </form>

}
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Thanks for your answer, this almost solved it. i used the line snippet "'first_name' => (isset($_GET['first_name'])),". This form should show a popup, the data has been sent to the array but the modal popup appears just a few seconds and goes away. does the action have to be in a different file?

Comment: The action doesn't need to be in a different file. You only have to check if the form is sent or not. I will update my answer.

Comment: What do you need to dispay in the popup ? The form itself or a confirmation message or anything else ?

Comment: The form has been submitted, the problem is now on the popup showing the result of the form, it only appears for a few seconds and then it goes away. the popup should persist until I close it manually

Comment: Can you update your post so we can test it ? I do not see the popup in your question...

Comment: I'm confused how to update the post, because this popup uses the API and runs in PHP. just now i tried to add action="javascript:void(0);" it manages to hold the popup but the form is not submitted

Comment: Then tell me which API you are using. Give me a link. Otherwise, if you prefer, I can show you my way to display the result in a popup.

Comment: Many thanks, for trying to help solve.
basically what I want to make like on this site: "https://komodo.midtrans.com/" by using the API "https://docs.midtrans.com/en/snap/overview"

Comment: I get a lot of issues trying to handle Midtrans. Maybe somebody can help you out...

Comment: If my answer helps you, even if it's not 100% the solution, you can upvote without checking it as a good answer ;)